# Event Listener with gsap

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-listener, gsap

I am having a problem here

```
const diplayes=document.querySelectorAll('.qq');
 for(const display of diplayes ){
 display.addEventListener('mouseover',()=>{

const tl = gsap.timeline({defaults:{ease:"power1.out"}});
tl.to('.div',{opacity:1, duration:1});
tl.to('span',{y:'0%', duration:1, stagger:0.25 },"-=1");
display.addEventListener('mouseleave',()=>{
    const tl = gsap.timeline({defaults:{ease:"power1.out"}});
    tl.fromTo('.div',{opacity:1},{opacity:0, duration:1});
    tl.to('span',{y:'10000%', duration:1, });
});

});
}
```

i have 3 separate divs so i want the event to happen individually but when hove over any div the event happen to all of the divs
what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You're making one of [the most common GSAP mistakes](https://greensock.com/mistakes/): using a general target instead of a specific one. As the linked article covers, what you should do instead is loop through all of your instances, create an animation for each, and attach event listeners for each one that refers to that specific animation. I talk more about that approach in my article on [animating efficiently](https://css-tricks.com/tips-for-writing-animation-code-efficiently/) which I highly recommend as well.

FYI you're more likely to get a faster response over on [the GSAP forums](https://greensock.com/forums/).